# I have installed rpm where does it installation log save in centos/redhat 6

Tags: centos, package-management, rpm

I have installed rpm where does it installation log save in centos 6. I mean which file stores the logs  for installation and removal of rpm and when we rum command rpm -qa --last from which file it get information and provide us the list of installed rpm.

Answer (score 2):

The information on installed rpms is held in a database that you can find split over several files in `/var/lib/rpm/`. You cannot use these files directly, but  must always use the `rpm` command to query it. For example, you can list specific info using `--queryformat` (abbreviated to `--qf`) followed by any tags from the list you get with `rpm --querytags`.

For example, you can get similar (unsorted) info to `rpm -qa --last` with

```
rpm -qa --qf '%{name} %{version}-%{release} %{installtime:date}\n'
```